# 部品 vs. 用品 - difference in usage

Tags: word-usage, pragmatics

Both 部品{ぶひん} and 用品{ようひん} are translated as **parts**.  Is there a difference in their usage?

Comment: Who told you 用品 meant "parts"?

Comment: "Parts" come from JMDict database, e.g. http://tangorin.com/general/%E7%94%A8%E5%93%81. I always suspected that JMDict entries should be taken with the grain of salt :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「部品{ぶひん}」 and 「用品{ようひん}」 mean totally different things; therefore, there should virtually be no interchangeability between the two.

「部品」 means "part(s)", "component(s)", etc. of a product.  From bolts to nuts and from springs to bearings, every little thing that is used to assemble a product is called 「部品」.

「用品」 is completely different.  It means a product used in a particular area of life, activity, etc.  It does NOT mean "part(s)".

For instance, 「テニス用品」 refers to all things needed for the game of tennis -- rackets, shoes, wear, strings, etc.

「キッチン用品」 would refer to plates, pots, pans, spatulas, etc.

「用品」, therefore, are already finished products in and of themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The "部品{ぶひん}" is the most widely used term as "parts." We seldom solely use the term "用品{ようひん}."

> 工場では、たくさんの部品が組み立てられて、完成品になります。
>   In manufacturing plants, thounsand of parts are assembled into finished products.
>
> 日用品{にちようひん} daily commoditiy
>   台所用品{だいどころようひん} kitchen wares
>   アウトドア用品{ようひん} outdoor gear

The term "用品" doesn't mean "parts" but products.

Comment: A helpful mnemonic is to note that 部 literally means "part" and 用 means "use".